# replace MapFragment inside viewPager

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Here's my problem. I have `RootMapFragment` in `viewPager` which is a container where I will have in future 2 different maps. `RootMapFragment` contain simple `FrameLayout` and with `FragmentTransaction` I want to replace `frame_layout` with marker_map in `onCreateView`. At first creation of marker_map everything is ok and the map is filled with markers which are got from `eventBus`. When in `viewPager` I have 3 tabs. Maps are in the first tab. When I get to second tab and back to the first tab, my app remembers earlier state of the map with markers, but when I go to the third tab, and back to first, app is creating new Instance of the map and it's empty. Is there a solution, where my app will remember the first state instead of creating new Instance of the map?

RootMapFragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.map.RootMapFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

RootMapFragment.java

```
public class RootMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment map;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_root_map, container, false);

        fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        map = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.marker_map);

        if (map == null) {
            map = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_map_fragment, new MarkerMapFragment()).commit();
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

MarkerMapFragment.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/marker_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.map.MarkerMapFragment" />
```

MarkerFragment.java

```
public class MarkerMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Bus bus = BusProvider.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onServerEvent(ServerEvent serverEvent) {

        List<Feature> features = serverEvent.getDataResponse().getFeatures();

        ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getContext(), mMap);
        clusterManager.setRenderer(new ClusterRenderer(getContext(), mMap, clusterManager));
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);

        for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {
            MarkerItem markerItem = new MarkerItem(features, i);
            clusterManager.addItem(markerItem);
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onErrorEvent(ErrorEvent errorEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + errorEvent.getErrorMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bus.register(this);

        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bus.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

method of `viewpager`

From documentation:

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

code:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

In your case, you need to  specify 2, so that when you are on the third page, the first one is not destroyed, and vice-versa.

Comment: Didn't expect I will be so easy :) It works, thanks ;)